# Queue disabled and HTTP 403 error

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience

I have already visited this [What does it mean to get 403 error when running a code on Qiskit?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/6571/what-does-it-mean-to-get-403-error-when-running-a-code-on-qiskit) which did not help me fix my problem.
I want to test the quantum circuit that I have designed using the following code, (the histogram of the circuit is being plotted perfectly so I don't believe that there is any problem with it)

```
IBMQ.load_account()
provider = IBMQ.get_provider('ibm-q')
qcomp = provider.get_backend('ibmq_16_melbourne')
job = execute(circuit, backend=qcomp)
```

I do not understand the problem with the above code. The last line is not executing in the Jupiter notebook cell. Is it a location problem of Melbourne, because me residence is India? What would I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the 403 because `ibmq_16_melbourne` is currently offline for maintenance. You can checkout the status of each backend on the IBM Quantum Experience website, or do `backend.status().operational`. Furthermore, you can get the least busy operational backend with something like

```
from qiskit.providers.ibmq import least_busy
backend = least_busy(provider.backends(simulator=False, filters=lambda b: 
    b.configuration().n_qubits >= 5))
```